# Android: What is this syntax doing?

Tags: java, android, syntax

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
   }

   public void onFinish() {
      mTextField.setText("done!");
   }
}.start();
```

Source: developer.android.com

I understand that it's creating a new object of class CountDownTimer, initialized with two parameters and finally started because it returns the same object. But the code with two functions between {} what kind of technique is? Are there any language references about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: `onTick()` is creating milliseconds into seconds and `onFinish()` is showing what to do as this `CountDownTimer` finishes.

Comment: It's simply showing (every second) the remaining time (in seconds) in a TextView called `mTextField`. Then it's showing "done!" on termination (after 30 secs), in the same TextView.

Comment: thank you guys but I know what the two functions will do. I had doubts about the technique of passing an entire block of methods when creating the object

Comment: you should add a better description of your doubt than   >  the code with two functions between {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountDownTimer` class is abstract : you can't instanciate it directly (it's a point of OOP, and so of every OO languages).

Your snippet creates an Anonymous class instance, as @Jon Skeet tells in comments. It means that you implements the abstract class and abstract methods directly, without "storing them" in a classic Java class.

Comment: Well, thank you. It's very useful.